# How can I delay fadeout of a dropdown menu trigger?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover, delay

I want an on hover on a logo to display a dropdown menu, but when i hover off it immediately disappears making it extremely difficult to access it. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydqad.jpg )

Ive been researching for a while and nothing seems to work.
Everything i can find just tells me to use the transition and transition delay CSS property but it doesnt seem to work

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu{
    transition: .5s all;
    transition-delay: 5s;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top">   
        <div class="nav-logo dropdown">
            <svg>
               LOGO GOES HERE
            </svg>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The dropdown menu should stay for about 5s after hover off, but it is not doing anything

Comment: You've tagged Bootstrap, yet you aren't using Bootstrap's suggested markup. Why?

Comment: Note that Bootstrap doesn't do hover menus because of their limited utility on touch devices. Simply adding some attributes to the trigger fixes things: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/n1sdy8q2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't add transition delay as `display` property is not animated in CSS.

What you could do is add simple JS code to add class on mouseover and timeout removal on mouseout.